# Rust feature flag for function outputs

Tags: rust

Consider the following type alias and function definitions:

```
#[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
pub type CompositeOutputType = (usize, String);
#[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
pub type CompositeOutputType = usize;

pub fn my_function(input: usize) -> CompositeOutputType {
    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    (input, ""); // Why it throws error without this semicolon?
    #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
    input
}
    
fn main() {
    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    let (output_1, output_2) = my_function(1);
    #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
    let output = my_function(1);
    
    println!("output: {:?}", output);
}
```

Is there a better way to write this in Rust, where the function output depends on the feature? Note that I can also defined `CompositeOutputType` as a struct instead, so then I do not need to worry about output being a single element or tuple, as it always will be a single object. Hence, my `main` function might simplify, but I was wondering if there is a better way to write this, to simplify outputting of `my_function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hence, my main function might simplify, but I was wondering if there is a better way to write this, to simplify outputting of my_function.

Modules?

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
mod inner {
    pub type CompositeOutputType = (usize, String);
    pub fn my_function(input: usize) -> CompositeOutputType {
        (input, "".to_string())
    }
}
#[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
mod inner {
    pub type CompositeOutputType = usize;
    
    pub fn my_function(input: usize) -> CompositeOutputType {
        input
    }
}

pub use inner::*;
```

though the entire thing seems misdesigned to me, changing the interface of a function entirely depending on a feature seems extremely wonky and error-prone, even with compiler support.

If a feature *requires* changing code, you might as well expose different types and functions entirely.